# Create Julian date from Carbon with Jalali in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-6, jalali-calendar

I have a expiration date for my file in database.

I want to convert it to julian persian date and compact it to the edit page.

This is my Controller:

```
Public function edit(Panelfile $panelfile)
{

$expiration = Jalalian::fromCarbon($panelfile->expiration)->format('Y-m-d');

$date = CalendarUtils::toJalali($expiration);

return view('file.edit',compact('panelfile','date'));
}
```

this is my datepicker input:

```
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" name"expiration" value="{{$date}}" data-jdp>
</div>
```

I get this error when I go to the edit page:

**Agrument 1 passed to Morilog\Jalali\Jalalian::fromCarbon() must be an intance of Carbon\Carbon, string given**

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
$expiration = Jalalian::fromCarbon($panelfile->expiration)->format('Y-m-d');
```

to this:

```
$expiration = Jalalian::fromCarbon(Carbon::parse($panelfile->expiration))->format('Y-m-d');
```

Now you have something like `1400-06-02` in `$expiration` (it's Jalali date).

If you take a look at `toJalali` method, it takes 3 argument:

```
/**
 * Converts a Gregorian date to Jalali.
 *
 * @param $gy
 * @param $gm
 * @param $gd
 * @return array
 * 0: Year
 * 1: Month
 * 2: Day
 */
public static function toJalali($gy, $gm, $gd)
{
    return self::d2j(self::g2d($gy, $gm, $gd));
}
```

You already have the Jalali date and (I think) you don't need to use the line after that.
But if you want to use `toJalali` method, you should pass three arguments to it:

1. Gregorian year (for example: 2021)
2. Gregorian month (for example: 8)
3. Gregorian day (for example: 24)

Comment: I tried it and got this error: Too few arguments Morilog\Jalali\CalendarUtils::to jalali(), 1 passed

Comment: I updated my answer. Please check it again.